# Limit requests per minute in nginx

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, web-server, load-balancing

I would like to set a limit on the number of requests a single client IP address can make to my server, based on their IP address. Nginx has a `limit_req_zone` directive. However, this directive will actually limit the *average* hits. If I set my limit to `rate=6r/m`, it will actually allow only one hit every 10 seconds.

Instead, what I need is an actual limit per minute. E.g. the client should be able to fire 3 or 4 requests quickly after each other or even simultaneously, but not more than e.g. 10 per minute. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

Ah I think this can be done with the `nodelay` setting as decribed at the bottom of the [limit_req wiki](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLimitReqModule):

*If delaying excess requests within a burst is not necessary, you should use the option nodelay:*

```
limit_req   zone=one  burst=5  nodelay;
```